# Why is std::pair<int, int> constructible from a const std::pair<int, float>&?

Tags: c++

It appears that a `std::pair<int, int>` is implicitly constructible from a `const std::pair<int, float>&` using the 4th definition from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, float>> v = { {1, 1.5f} };

    // The interesting line:
    const std::pair<int, int>& x = v[0];

    const auto& y = v[0];

    std::cout << "before:\n";
    std::cout << "\tv[0]: " << std::get<1>(v[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tx:    " << std::get<1>(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\ty:    " << std::get<1>(y) << "\n";

    std::get<1>(v[0]) = 3.5f;

    std::cout << "\nafter:\n";
    std::cout << "\tv[0]: " << std::get<1>(v[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tx:    " << std::get<1>(x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\ty:    " << std::get<1>(y) << "\n";
}
```

The output is

```
before:
    v[0]: 1.5
    x:    1
    y:    1.5

after:
    v[0]: 3.5
    x:    1
    y:    3.5
```

([ideone link](http://ideone.com/5jyiwD))

It seems awkward that `x` "feels" less like a reference than `y` (in that it is (legitimately) a reference to what is probably the "wrong" thing from the user's perspective.)

What is the rationale for that constructor not being marked `explicit`? (I'm assuming there is an important use case.)

Comment: I'll note for the future: std::tuple has a similar constructor.

Comment: @Dave: why would `explicit` not make a difference? It seems to me that it should, and that the conversion to a temporary to bind to the const reference is an implicit conversion. For example http://ideone.com/k6qd6l

Comment: I've unmarked Dave's answer as accepted in light of SteveJessop's comment.

Comment: Steve is right, it would not help if the user code did `std::pair<int,int>& x = std::pair<int,int>(v[0]);` as the conversion would be explicit, but it would work in the original code as copy-initialization requires implicit conversions (only direct-initialization can use explicit conversions)

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right in your example, but that's not equivalent to `std::pair`. The constructor being hit is `template<class U1, class U2> pair(const pair<U1, U2>& p);`

Comment: What about this http://ideone.com/lBCJpI ? If I remove "explicit" it compiles.

Comment: @JacobParker Ya, I was wrong. It does matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// The interesting line:
const std::pair<int, int>& x = v[0];
```

That code is equivalent to:

```
const std::pair<int,int>& x = std::pair<int,int>(v[0]);
```

The issue that surprised you is that, due to the existence of a conversion from `std::pair<int,float>` to `std::pair<int,int>` the compiler is allowed (and required) to create a temporary and bind the const reference to that. If you remove the `const` (and you are not using VS) the code should fail.

Comment: For sure, that was my understanding/guess at what was happening. What I'm curious about is "why" that constructor exists at all, or why it is not marked explicit.

Comment: @JacobParker: That constructor is meant to provide an element wise conversion, and should only participate in overload resolution if both members are element-wise implicitly convertible (in C++11, in C++03 the standard said something different but it was impossible to implement, so it did explicit conversions). The idea, I guess, is that if the elements are convertible, why not make the type convertible? Also note that this is often used with the standard library: `std::map<int,int>().insert(std::make_pair(1,2))` uses that exact same conversion [`value_type` is `std::pair<const int,int>`]

Comment: @david-rodriguez-dribeas ah, the std::map<A,B>::insert example is good. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with this answer, to me the confusion isn't caused by the `pair` constructor (i.e. conversion) existing or being implicit. It's caused by the fact that initializing a const reference can do a conversion at all. You'd be just as surprised by `const int &i = vector_of_floats[0];`. So it's not `pair`'s fault in particular, and for *any* conversion you could make the same point, this surprising code could be prevented by making the conversion explicit.

Comment: ... but I assume the reason this reference initialization is permitted, is for consistency with other reference initializations where you definitely want a conversion in order to bind to a const reference. For example, `void foo(const std::string &s); foo("bar");`

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not a reference to `v[0]`, it's a reference to an object of type `std::pair<int, int>` which matches the lifetime of `x`. When you initialize a `const T&`, a new object will be constructed from the right hand side if a direct reference isn't possible.

In this case, what you wrote would have been the same as writing:

```
const std::pair<int, int> x = v[0]; // note: no reference
```

You should probably get a warning about this though, because of the float to int conversion.